# ADF Override Linked Service Key Vault Reference

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I have a linked service and I am trying to change the Azure Key Vault Reference (this is the view of authoring instance)

[image]

I am using git integration and in my authoring instance I have set it up using a key vault reference however, when I deploy this it changes it to using password (see below).

[image]

I have added the **arm-template-parameters-definition.json** file so it allows me to override this but for some reason its not keeping the key vault reference.

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices": {
    "*": {
        "properties": {
            "typeProperties": {
                "baseUrl": "=",
                "serviceEndpoint": "=",
                "credential": {
                    "referenceName": "="
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                    "store": {
                        "referenceName": "=",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    }
                }
            },
            "connectVia": {
                "referenceName": "="
            }
        }
    }
},
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to have the correct behaviour when I use Key Vault for the entire connection string (picture below shows the deployed instance with expected behaviour), doesn't seem to like just the password in key vault.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should not be necessary to add this file (arm-template-parameters-definition.json).

In your Data Factory under "Manage" -> "ARM template" -> "Edit parameter configuration" you find the definition and the BaseUrl. It should already be parameterized per default (`"baseUrl": "=",`). The file contains already many settings. If you have any other parameters you need, just edit this file inside the Data Factory.

If you have cloned the repository locally and checked out the adf_publish branch, inside the folder which is name after your Data Factory you will find the file ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json where the parameters are. Those can be overwritten for example in the deployment script for another data factory (on another environment).

Comment: The override works for base address but I have added a new screenshot and its swapping it from an `Azure Key Vault Reference` to a `Password`.